# Create multi-page document from a single page template using doc4j

Tags: docx4j

I am planning to use doc4j for search and replace in a template. I'do like to create the page for each member in the list.  Basically, I need to replicate the same page from the template.  I have done simple search and replace. However, this little complex one for which I need some sample examples. Here is my requirement:

1. I have a docx template which has the content with place holders.
2. There is a table with  3 columns in it and I need to replace with different values for each column like first name, last name and etc. The number of rows may vary anywhere from one to 200. So technically this may go beyond one page. If it exceeds more than one page, then I need the table header to repeat in the next page too.
3. I want to copy the same template on every page and replace the place holder. Basically create a single document with multiple pages each page for one member.

Please provide me with the example.
Appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: See my answer to your cross post at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/create-multi-page-document-from-a-single-page-template-using-t2369.html

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I'll look into this and update the results.